# What happened to my remaining money?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india, salary

I was offered an Internship at a company with a monthly amount of 15000 rupees. I joined on 6th january 2015. I was paid an amount of 13065 rupees today to my bank account. Where did the remaining amount go. My friend says its TDS.

I searched net and found base taxable income is 2L per year. My doubt is did they deduct the tax? I have no problem if they do. How do I know they did? Or did they pay me from 6th january? i.e, 6th to 31st or 6th Jan to 6th Feb. I have no clue about these things. So please help me. I live in India and I am an Indian citizen.

Comment: Do they not send you a pay stub? It's probably both, taxes and the days you did not work for that month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salaries in India are generally paid of the month. If you have joined mid-month like you mention on 6th Jan. The first salary will be for part month.

In your case it would be (15000/31) Multiply by 27 Days. Rs 13065.

You should get a salary slip that would give more details.